# Open neighborhood of the identity in general linear group with no proper subgroup.

Tags: representation-theory

I'm trying to prove that there exists an open neighborhood of the identity in the complex general linear group that contains no proper subgroup.  This is needed to show that a continuous representation of a profinite group has open kernel.  Any help is appreciated.